# Lua, XML, UTF-8

Tags: xml, lua, luaxml

I'm using luaxml lib for generating xml files after database selects from lua tables. All is good, but I am using Russian symbols in my DB (NySQL). What I need to do with luaxml to represents this symbols not with codes (a-la Ð) but with a real symbols.
I found method function xml.registerCode(decoded,encoded) but don't understand nothing :(

Or, maybe, I need to use another lib. And if so - what lib?

Comment: Please include more details. At least the functions you are calling, their parameters, the expected results and the results you are obtaining.

Comment: What do you mean by "real symbols"?

Comment: What encoding is used by your DB, and what encoding do you put in xml headers?
Do you modify strings before writing them to xml?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked inside the lib - it does forceful encoding for all >127 bytes, thus breaking UTF into separate characters. It does it after using its built-in `.registerCode` mechanism, so you can't even override it.

If you need to encode some complex data structure, you can just unroll all those entity substitutions after `XmlLua` finished stringifying by declaring somewhere:

```
local high_ascii_unroll = {}
for code = 128, 255 do
    high_ascii_unroll['&#' .. code .. ';'] = string.char(code)
end
```

and then using `gsub` on final string:

```
local doc = xml.new("outer")
doc.version = "2.0"
local inner = xml.new("inner")
inner.id = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫьЭЮЯ"
table.insert(doc, inner)

local encoded = xml.str(doc):gsub('&#%d+;', high_ascii_unroll)
-- <outer version="2.0">
--  <inner id="АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫьЭЮЯ" />
-- </outer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking inside LuaXML_lib.c, there is a method called char2code() which replaces characters not in the ASCII range with numeric entities. You can "unbreak" it by replacing the method with the following:

```
static const char* char2code(unsigned char ch, char buf[2]) {
    buf[0]=ch;
    buf[1]=0;
    return buf;
}
```

This stops it from replacing any invalid characters with entities. It will then be up to you to make sure there are no invalid characters in your input, but it definitely won't mangle your UTF-8 any more.